# How do you properly forward Domain name from 1and1 to an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been attempting to forward my domain EmblemsOnDemand.com which is managed on 1and1.com to an AWS EC2 instance (Prestashop Lamp Stack) however when I do so the domain name forwards to the EC2 instance however the name resolves as ec2-52-34-87-245.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.

I would like it to stay EmblemsOnDemand.com and not my automatically generated AWS instance domain.  I already assigned an elastic IP to the instance and a Hosted Zone with the following  name server settings for 1and1, where I purchased the domain:

```
NS-0 ns-1871.awsdns-41.co.uk
NS-1 ns-959.awsdns-55.net
NS-2 ns-1212.awsdns-23.org
NS-3 ns-24.awsdns-03.com
```

[image: Route 53 settings]

Other Details: Bitnami Lamp Stack w/ Prestashop on Ubuntu

Also, when I ping the AWS IP, 1and1 Domain, and AWS Domain nothing happens (Request Times Out) however I can SSH, SCP, everything using the any of the IPs/Domains. What am I missing?  Thanks for reading this far :)

I have manged to temporarily fix the problem by modifying the htaccess.conf file which takes the place of the .htaccess file as it is more secure however when I reset the the server something overwrites my settings I save, and since I fixed it the one time it doesn't even temporarily fix the issue anymore, it does nothing.

[image: htaccess.conf file keeps getting "EmblemsOnDemand.com overwritten with "ec2-52-34-87-245.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"]

Comment: Regarding ping: You need to enable ICMP in your security group.

Comment: Thanks John.  I have no real desire for ping, I just wanted to see if there was an underlying issue associated with the failed pings. ;)